# Is this invalid usage of the class Type?

Tags: c#

Is this not what `Type` is able to offer? Is there another way I can achieve the below?

```
Type t = typeof(Int32);
List<t> list = new List<t>();
```

This seems valid usage to me based on what the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.7.2) mentioned:

> Represents type declarations: class types, interface types, array
>   types, value types, enumeration types, type parameters, generic type
>   definitions, and open or closed constructed generic types

But I have a feeling [this](https://www.dotnetperls.com/type) is a better description which means that I cannot use the class `Type` as above as it seems to only hold information about the type:

> Type describes data types. It stores type information in a variable,
>   property or field. The Type class represents the program's metadata,
>   which is a description of its structure but not the instructions that
>   are executed.

I was trying to use the above in order to solve a problem where I have a 'List' where `t` is a user defined type, that list gets stored within a field of type `object` I will at some point later on need to parse it back to it's original type, I was hoping that the class `Type` will allow me to retain the type for parsing back to the original later on.

I am after something like this:

```
public IList ObjectToList(Type t, object o)
{
    return new List<t>(o);
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do in the first place? Generics mean you *don't* need to specify the type. Just as `List<T>` can be used to create lists of any type, `MakeList<T>=>new List<T>();` can do the same

Comment: Why do you believe `Represents type declarations` should be an description for type can be used to create a type of array/list? - A type is a `reprenstation` or the various possible types so `Type t = typeof(List<int>);` will `represent` the `Type` of a `List<int>`

Comment: Try this: `List<int> list = new List<int>();`

Comment: @Abs This looks like a case of the XY Problem. You have a problem with X and think Y is the answer. When you encounter problems with Y, you ask about Y, not X. What is the *actual* problem you want to solve?

Comment: @OwenPauling This isn't a duplicate because the problem I am trying to address here is to convert an existing list stored within an `object` back to a list of the correct type while the marked question creates a new list from a `Type`, my edit explains this, not sure if you've seen it before marking as a duplicate

Comment: Here's your method: ```IList<T> ObjectToList<T>(object obj) => obj as List<T> ?? new List<T>();```

Comment: Here's your list: ```var persons = new List<Person>()
{
     new Person("Mathew", "Mark"),
     new Person("Luke", "John")
};```

Comment: Here's your casting: ```object obj = persons;
var list = ObjectToList<Person>(obj);```

Comment: ```foreach (var person in list) Console.WriteLine(person.First);```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a valid usage because it will not compile. The Type class *represents* a type declaration. `Type t = typeof(Int32);` will give you the `System.Type` object for `Int32` and assign to the variable `t`. It cannot actually be used as a type.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Runtime variable as Type identifier.

```
Type t = typeof(Int32);
```

actually holds type of `Int32` inside variable `t`

---

you can use it

```
List<Int32> list = new List<Int32>();
```